# Compilation failing with pattern matching on Number type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Following is my code where I am trying to check what type is each `a` in `t`.

```
for (a <- t) {
  for (b <- a) {
    def get_type(obj: Any) = obj match {
      case n: Number => println("n is an integer equal to: ")
      case s: String => println("$s is a String")
      case _ => println("Error: unmatched type")
    }
    get_type(b)
  }
}
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
[error] /home/plard/Desktop/modified_peacock_src/gps_example/../template/Actors/Save.scala:82: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
[error]  found   : Number
[error]  required: String
[error]                         case n: Number => println ("n is a Number equal to: ")
[error]                                 ^
[error] one error found
```

Does anyone know for what reason does it happen, please?

Comment: What is the type of `t` ?

Comment: t is an ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]().

Comment: Your code works here, are you sure your `obj` parameter is `Any` in the code you tested (if I replace it with `String`, I get the same error) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as expected when I use it in this way:

```
val t = new ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]
t += Array("1", "2", "3")                         
t += Array("4", "5", "6")
for (a <- t)
  for (b <- a) {
    def get_type(obj: Any) = obj match {
      case n: Number => println("n is an integer equal to: ")
      case s: String => println("$s is a String")
      case _         => println("Error: unmatched type")
  };
  get_type(b)
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
n is a String 
n is a String
n is a String
n is a String
n is a String 
n is a String
```

If you simplify the code a bit, you can create the same error:

```
  1 match {
    case n: Number => println("n is an integer equal to: ")
    case s: String => println("$s is a String")
    case _         => println("Error: unmatched type")
  }
```

This should actually result in two errors:

```
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;  found   : Number  required: Int
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;  found   : String  required: Int
```

However, it does not happen with the code, you have provided above, because the type of `obj` is `Any` not `Int`.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to precise that t is an ArrayBuffer[Array[String]](), which might impact your answer.

Comment: I have modified the code to reflect the change in t's type.